# Binding cannot be cast to binding error on navigation

Tags: android, kotlin

I use fragments with navigation in my app. I have the mainFragment class and the adminPwdFragment class. I want to go from the mainFragment to the adminPwdFragment with the press of a button on the interface. But I always get this error when tapping the button :

> 2020-05-16 17:12:53.302 1423-1423/com.example.lejosremote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.lejosremote, PID: 1423
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.lejosremote.databinding.MainFragmentBindingImpl cannot be cast to com.example.lejosremote.databinding.AdminPwdFragmentBinding
>           at com.example.lejosremote.admin_pwd.onCreateView(admin_pwd.kt:20)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2222)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1995)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1951)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Here are the classes

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

private lateinit var binding: MainFragmentBinding

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    // Inflate view and obtain an instance of the binding class
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.main_fragment,
        container,
        false
    )

    //        ligne pour créer le ViewModel une seule fois
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    binding.mainViewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    viewModel.eventAdmin.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { admin ->
        if (admin) {
            findNavController().navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToAdminPwd())
        }
    })

    return binding.root
}
```

admin_pwd is for the other fragment:

```
class admin_pwd : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModel: AdminPwdViewModel
private lateinit var viewModelFactory: AdminPwdViewModelFactory

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val binding: AdminPwdFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.main_fragment,
        container,
        false
    )


    viewModelFactory = AdminPwdViewModelFactory()
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AdminPwdViewModel::class.java)

    binding.mainViewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    return binding.root
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I get rid of this error and make the navigation happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this in `admin_pwd` fragment

```
 val binding: AdminPwdFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.main_fragment,
        container,
        false
    )
```

to

```
val binding: AdminPwdFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.admin_pwd_fragment,
        container,
        false
    )
```